# Screen going black, further investigation reveals healthy ram and hard disk, and several kernel oops logs

Tags: 14.04, crash

Six days ago, I went to go take a shower, and I suspended Ubuntu as usual, to save battery life. I came back, and the screen was black.

REISUB and general fiddling around did nothing. Restarted, and still had nothing on the screen. Since then, this has happened several times, and the only fix is to

1. force shut laptop,
2. take out battery,
3. hold power button,
4. put battery back in,
5. boot.

I have investigated further into the matter, doing a ram test and a hard disk check. Both turned out fine.

Then my attention turned towards the error messages I was receiving upon bootup, the whole `System program problem detected` deal. I did some digging and found four kernel oops logs in my `/var/crash`.
What I can understand of them points to two things:

1. They are connected to my suspending problems, since there are four them (I have had four suspending crashes), and they both confirm that there was a issue with waking up from suspend, and
2. The crashes might have to do with Python (possibly could be jumping to conclusions), since mentions of Python are peppered throughout the logs.

At this point, I am unsure of how to continue, and I have come here for help. Is there any way I can fix this? Should I start by uploading the logs here?

EDIT: I uploaded the crash reports to Google Drive, because all of them were too big for pastebin or paste.ubuntu.com. I know putting them in a zip file might have messed up the files somewhat, but the files by themselves were not uploading for some reason.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bw62lS9pZtQ2SWc2Z2pOSy05Qlk&usp=sharing

Comment: Providing the logs is the first step to solving your issue, but since logs are usually long try pasting them in the [Ubuntu Patebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and then edit your question and provide us the link.

Comment: Alright, I am attempting to upload them, but the files are obnoxiously large for text files (500 - 700+ KB) and I am unable to paste the entire thing. I'll just upload them to my Google drive and post a link to the folder here.

Comment: Post edited to include link.

Comment: I cannot veiw your crash logs, there is an error

Comment: Try viewing it now.

Comment: Alright, it took me long enough to get to it, but I managed to get a crash log file pasted. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8170263/

Answer (score 0):

If you beleve it is apyton error please tyr the following python version and PPA

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.3
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If this does not help please post the /var/crash logs you mentioned

Comment: I'll do this just in case it works, but I'm posting the crash logs as well.

Comment: Post edited to include link.